Why doesn't the Image I Added Completely Cover My Background?
enter image description here
body {
    background-image: url('/images/largest.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

How exactly can I cover the background of my page?

You may wanna set the width and the height of your body to 100%. See if that works. Standard its not applied. Also, i wouldnt recommend putting it on the body, i think some browsers don't support it (dont quote me on it), you may be better of putting it in a container over the whole page.

Yourbody should fill the screen so set minimum height to screen height:
 min-height: 100vh;

Hope it helps ^_^
